# ISO-8859-9/Latin-9 encoding

Tags: encoding, ascii, iso, latin

I know it exist ISO-8859-**9**/Latin-**5** or ISO-8859-**15**/Latin-**9**, but recently I had to manage some messages encoded with ISO-8859-**9**/Latin-**9** format.
What does it exactly mean?

Comment: It probably means there is a typo.

Comment: I think an error. Some people confuse the two suffixes, and whtn typing it is also common to get numbers wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **ISO-8859-9** which is called **Latin-5**.
And there is **ISO-8859-15** which is called **Latin-9**.

Yes, it is confusing. In my opinion it's simplest to always only use the ISO-8859-*n* moniker. That avoids potential confusions.

So "ISO-8859-9/Latin-9" is probably a typo (or someone wrongly thought that the suffix is identical for the "ISO-8859-" and the "Latin-" prefix).

Depending on the source of the data, you can guess which one they meant. ISO-8859-9 is used for Turkish text and ISO-8859-15 is basically the modern replacement for ISO-8859-1 (covering most of Western Europe, mostly used because it has the € symbol).

Source: [ISO/IEC 8859 Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#The_parts_of_ISO/IEC_8859).